# Switch radio button for image where image is pulled in using php

Tags: php, jquery, image, radio-button

I have a calculator of sorts working with a database and where I have a radio button, I need to use jquery to switch all radio buttons for the images being pulled in by ID. This is just one of the lines within the form (the form data is being captured in the clients CRM in intouch. However, I'm a bit of a newb when it comes to jquery and I can't get it to work.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
    <input name="CustomField:12875:2" type="radio" value="<?php echo $r['intouch_id']; ?>" data-name="<?php echo $r['name']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" <?php if($range == $r['id']){ ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?>>  <img src="images/style-img/<?php echo $r['id'].'.jpg' ?>" />  <?php echo $r['name']; ?><br>
</div>
```

I've tried implementing various things like from this helpful link: [Replace radio buttons with images using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587991/replace-radio-buttons-with-images-using-jquery) and also: [CSS+HTML Radio button - every button have other img how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342936/csshtml-radio-button-every-button-have-other-img-how)

but to no avail due to my images being pulled in by php from a folder with images with IDs?

Any help at all or a solution would be most appreciated.

Many thanks

G

Comment: Can you show the jQuery code you have tried?

Comment: I've deleted it now as it wasn't working, however they were variations as shown in the 2 links above. My jquery unfortunately is not strong and I couldn't get it working at all. Not sure if this helps?

Comment: So you want to switch a radio button to an image when the radio button is clicked?

Comment: No. I need different images to show and be clickable as radio buttons  - when clicked it will have a dark blue border - the actual radio buttons would need to be hidden. The difficulty I'm having is that there is one php function calling in several images by ID from a folder... I was working around the theory of something along the lines of: Search for the ID of the radio button and once found, replace it with an image of the same ID (but from that specific category)... there are various categories being referred to... for instance $r = range $s = size etc. Not sure if this helps?

Comment: Image is being brought in using: <img src="images/style-img/<?php echo $r['id'].'.jpg' ?> - so i need to switch the radio buttons with identical ID's for images.

Comment: Got this resolved in the end with javascript! Thanks all.